# Probability two blocks have exactly 2 out of 4 properties the same?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> I have 120 blocks. Each block is one of 2 different materials, 3 different colors, 4 different sizes, and 5 different shapes. No two blocks have exactly the same of all four properties. I take two blocks at random. What is the probability the two blocks have exactly two of these four properties the same?

I ended up getting:
$${{\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}}\over{\binom{120}{2}}} = {{41}\over{238}}$$Is this correct?

**EDIT:** The answer given here is ${{35}\over{119}} = {5\over{17}}$:
https://web2.0calc.com/questions/probability-question-blocks

Who is correct?

Comment: At a glance, yes, it looks correct

Comment: You can’t be right.  After choosing the first block (it doesn’t matter which one you choose), there are $119$ left to choose from, of which exactly $x$ satisfy the given constraint.  So the answer must be $x/119$ for some integer $x$.

Comment: And $x$ should be $2+3+4+6+8+12=35$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4197246) is incorrect. The expression $${{\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}}\over{\binom{120}{2}}}$$ simplifies to $\frac{35}{238} = \frac{5}{34}$  when we compute it carefully; this is only half the correct answer of $\frac{5}{17}$.

The mistake in this approach is subtle. The problem is that the numerator counts the number of ways to choose a single value for two properties and a pair of values for the other two properties.  For example, something counted by the numerator is "wooden, red, big+small, round+square". However, there are two ways to put this together into a pair of blocks that agree in exactly two properties: the pair "big red wooden square block + small red wooden round block", and the pair "big red wooden round block + small red wooden square block". So we must multiply by $2$ to account for this.

[M. Wind's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4197037) already gives a quicker way to get the correct answer. Another way to get there without changing the approach is to cancel some common factors.

For example, $\binom21 \binom31\binom 42 \binom 52$ can be written as $2 \cdot 3 \cdot \frac{4 \cdot 3}{2} \cdot \frac{5\cdot 4}{2}$. Let's not be in a hurry to simplify this. One of the divisions by $2$ cancels from the correction above; the other cancels with the division by $2$ in $\binom{120}{2} = \frac{120 \cdot 119}{2}$. Also, $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 = 120$ is present in all six terms, and cancels with the $120$ in the numerator. After canceling, we are left with
$$
   \frac{3 \cdot 4 + 2 \cdot 4 + 2 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 4 + 1 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 2}{119} = \frac{5}{17}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

No. The answer given on the linked website is correct.

After picking the first block there are 119 left. Assume that the second block has material and color the same, whereas size and shape are different. Of the $4*5 = 20$ blocks that meet the first criterium (note: minus 1 because the first block can not be picked again!), it is easy to see that there are $(4-1)*(5-1) = 12$ that satisfy the second criterium. Analyzing the other combinations in the same way we get:

$$P = \frac {3*4 + 2*4 + 2*3 +1*4 + 1*3+1*2} {119} = \frac {12+8+6+4+3+2}{119} = \frac {35}{119}$$

Comment: I am not sure what your formula actually is accomplishing. I suggest that you compute every term in your formula, and then check whether it matches the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

You have made a simple arithmetic error. I evaluated your expression and I got $\dfrac{5}{17}$.

Comment: Actually, the expression in the question gives $\frac{5}{34}$, not $\frac{5}{17}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Since no two blocks have all four properties identical, and $2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5=120$, there are exactly enough blocks for every combination of properties; thus each arrangement has identical probability.  Hence you can use this method.

The denominator counts the ways to select 2 among these 120 combinations, of course.  This is the size of the sample space.

Your numerator counts the ways to select one of two properties and two of the other for each of the six such arrangements of properties.  Thus properly counting the favoured outcomes.

So... everything checks out okay.